# Determine camera shooting angle of a 3D object from a 2D image?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm trying to determine the angle/position of a camera relative to a 3D object (that it is taking a picture of) from a labeled dataset.

The dataset contains the captured 2D image the camera took of the 3D object. The data is labeled with the actual orientation of the camera when it took that image.

Any resources as to what this kind of fitting is called? (e.g. determining the perspective viewing angle of a 3D object from a 2D image). Would TensorFlow fit this sort of challenge given a large and labeled dataset (10,000+ 2D images)?

Comment: if the dataset contains the 2d image and is labeled with the orientation of the camera, why do you want to determin the orientation of the camera? I don't get what you want

Comment: To determine the camera Pose from 2D correspondence the PnP method is used. You can take a look at [OpenCV solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) You can also read Gao's [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1217599)

Comment: The "fitting" is called PnP, from "Pose and Position". It's a well known and solved problem in photogrammetry. See here: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d2c/tutorial_real_time_pose.html

What exactly are you trying to accomplish by training a machine learning system on these data?

Comment: @Piglet because I want it to eventually work on an unlabeled dataset (same 3D object, unknown orientation.
Kochoba : thank you! will take a look.
FrancescoCallari: I want to be able to recognize orientation of a 3D object from a 2D image without any labeling. e.g. I have some labeled data now of the 3D object in many different orientations. In the future, I want to be able to recognize the orientatino of the 3D object no matter what orientation it is in (e.g. a live demo where a user can rotate the object however she wants but the 2D camera can still identify its orientation/bounding box)

Comment: And you can't just match keypoints to an image (or images) of the same object in a canonical pose (or poses)? Again, what is it that you want the machine to learn? The point/feature matching? For a rigid object and a pinhole camera the geometry of this problem is entirely understood, the matching is the only image-dependent part.